# Summand is not numerical at some point

Tags: numerical-integration, summation

I am trying to do some numerical integration with the following codes:

```
EI[m_, x_] := x^m/m! (0.5772156649 + Log[x] - HarmonicNumber[m]) + Sum[If[k != m, x^k/((k - m)*k!), 0], {k, 0, Infinity}];
phi[m_, n_, x_] := (-1)^(n + 1)*m^n*Sum[(-Pi^2)^k*Binomial[n, 2*k + 1]*(EI[m, x])^(n - 2*k - 1)*(x^m/m!)^(2*k + 1), {k, 0, Floor[(n - 1)/2]}];
F[n_, m_, t_] := NIntegrate[((1 - Exp[-t*x])*Exp[-n*x]*phi[m, n, x])/x, {x, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

They worked fine when I calculated `F[10, 24, 0.4] // Timing`.
But when $m>24$, for example, `F[10, 25, 0.4]// Timing`,
I got an error saying

> NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) If[k!=25,x^k/((k-25) k!),0] is not numerical at point k = 15.

and for`F[10, 26, 0.4]// Timing`, an error saying

> NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) If[k!=26,x^k/((k-26) k!),0] is not numerical at point k = 15.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a extended comment: Sadly I'm not sure which version should we use to reproduce the warning mentioned in the question. (I should have recorded it 7 years ago! ) Anyway, `NIntegrate` gives a seemingly reasonable result in *v9.0.1*:

[image]

While in *v12.3.1* the `Throw::sysexc` warning pops up. If the `WorkingPrecision -> 30` is removed, `NIntegrate::ncvb` pops up and `3.49077*10^35` is given as output, which no longer looks reasonable.

Not sure which result is reliable. Perhaps none of them?